# While loop doesn't seem to be incrementing

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, bufferedreader, increment

My code basically looks like this:

```java
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputFile));

    while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

         Document document;
         DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
         document = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(currentLine)));
         document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
         NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("record");

         int j = 0;
         int k = 0;
         while (j < lines) {
             if (currentLine.contains(bList.get(k))) {
                 myList.add(currentLine);
                 bufferedReader.mark(0);
                 k++;
                 j++;
             }
             else if (myList.size() == bList.size()) {
                 break;
             }
             else {
                 j++;
             }
         }
```

I have a bufferedReader which goes through a file line by line. What I want is for a single occurrence of line to be added to myList, based on whether that line contains a string which exists in bList. For whatever reason, when I debug, bList doesn't move to the next index despite the k++ incrementation. I'm also unsure if using bufferedReader.mark(0) is the right move here, I previously used inputFile.getChannel().position(0); but I was met with:

> 'Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity'

Another issue I noticed when debugging is that the while loop doesn't break when the size of myList and bList are equal. Instead, myList makes it all the way to a size of 34 whilst bList remains at a size of 2.

> EDIT: Added more lines for a bit of context and understanding

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that adds anything to `bList`, why do you expect it to grow? Also, `currentLine` is never changed and I don't see a `BufferedReader` call in there anywhere. All in all, the code doesn't seem to match your description. Could you update whichever one is wrong, please?

Comment: Did you mean to update `currentLine` somewhere in your loop?

Comment: Can you add your xml, so that we can point, where is the incorrect structure?

Comment: @DmitriyPopov I'm unable to add my XML file due to GDPR.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I don't expect bList to grow, I expect myList to grow

Comment: @khelwood it does iterate through each line in the XML

Comment: abidount: No, the code you posted doesn't iterate through anything. Nothing updates `currentLine`. If your real code does that, then you need to post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You "censor" so much of your code that it's pointless to argue about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

k will never be incremented if currentline does not contain whatever is in bList @ index k and will therefore be stuck at this word.

if currentline contains the thing in bList `else if (myList.size() == bList.size())` won't be executed, and you don't want to use break, that is just bad style. Instead go for `while(... && myList.size() < bList.size()`)

Also I don't understand the logic behind adding the same line to myList several times, you probably want to iterate over other lines.

What is the purpose of `bufferedReader.mark(0);`?

Here is some code that should do what you want:

```
  LinkedList<String> found = new LinkedList<String>();
  while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    foreach(String word : bList){
      if(!found.contains(word) && currentline.contains(word)){
        myList.add(currentLine);
        found.add(word);
        break;      
      }
    }
  }
```

this adds every line to myList the first time it contains a word from bList.
alternatively you can delete the word from bList if you don't need bList anymore.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I don't want k to be incremented unless it is found within the currentLine, but even when it is, it still does not get incremented.

The buffered reader also does iterate over the whole XML.

The ```bufferedReader.mark(0)``` is for the bufferedReader to start from the beginning once the occurrence of ```bList(k)``` is found. As it will then need to find the first occurrence of ```bList(k+n)``` in that same XML.

Comment: @abiodunt: that's not what `mark` does at all! If you never call `reset()` then `mark()` does effectively nothing. Also, as repeated over and over again: you **never read from the buffered reader in your code**!

Comment: @JoachimSauer I've added some additional lines for context. Also, how would I go about resetting the buffered reader to line 1. When calling ```reset()``` I am met with >java.io.IOException: Stream not marked

Comment: you don't even need that, you are reading line by line already why would you mark anything?

Comment: @ChristianO. I wanted to make the buffered reader start from line 1 again after finding an occurrence of bList(k). I initially used ```inputFile.getChannel().position(0);``` but got an exception.

Comment: but why? you already check the line for every element of bList, that would just lead to an endless loop,  line has word -> check again, still has the word -> check again...

Comment: @ChristianO. The reason I want to restart the buffered reader is because I am looking for the first occurrence. The first occurrence of bList(0) may be on line 50, but the first occurrence of bList(1) may be on line 10. I understand that this could cause an infinite loop which is why I put that else if statement, but it never runs that part of the code.

Comment: the first occurence of what? you already check line 0 for an occurence of every element in blist. See the code i added to my answer...

Comment: @ChristianO. I tested the code you added to your answer. It added all 197 lines from the xml file to myList. I should mention that within the xml, each line is different, so there is no point using a HashSet. They only have one thing in common, which is what the elements in bList are and that is what I wish to separate them based on.

Comment: @ChristianO. seem to have done it by adding ```bList.remove(word);``` after ```myList.add(currentLine);```. Thanks very much for the help.